# Vim pauses if echo in .vimrc file

Tags: linux, vim, debian

I'm having a little problem with vim. I'm using Debian testing and --version gives

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Dec  1 2011 03:25:24)
```

In my .vimrc file, if I use an echo statement, it will pause the running of vim with the following statement:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then vim will run as normal. This was from adding simply:

```
echo "Hello"
```

to the bottom of .vimrc

How can I stop this pausing behaviour, if at all?

Thanks,
Narnie

Comment: Where do you expect it to display the text, if it can't pause?

Comment: I was expecting it to appear at the bottom of the Vim window just as if one types :echo "Hello" However, I think this is because it runs this before setting up the vim "screen," so it is printing it beforehand in the shell before starting up the vim screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:silent !echo Hello
```

will do the trick.

~~~
From the OP, this worked:

```
let colorScheme = "evening"
silent execute "!echo setting color scheme to " . colorScheme
```

Comment: Using the shell echo instead of vim echo is a great idea, but I need access to vim variables for what I'm wanting to echo. Code example:

let colorScheme = "evening"
echo "setting color scheme to" . colorScheme

Comment: Using the shell echo instead of vim echo is a great idea, but I need access to vim variables for what I'm wanting to echo. Code example:

let colorScheme = "evening"
echo "setting color scheme to" . colorScheme

but this did work based on your idea:

silent execute "!echo setting color scheme to " . colorScheme