# how to have an echo statement run after vimrc has loaded?

Tags: vim

I frequently switch between machines, and I would like to be reminded of the number of colors supported when I start vim.

My .vimrc is copied on all of the machines.

I have tried adding the line:

```
echo 'Terminal t_Co: ' &t_Co
```

However, vim displays this message in the shell and requires me to press ENTER to continue:

```
snowch:~/.vim$ vim .vimrc 
Terminal t_Co:  8
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**Question**: how can I get the message echoed after vim has started?

---

**Note**: I have seen the question [Vim pauses if echo in .vimrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171059/vim-pauses-if-echo-in-vimrc-file) and I believe it is asking a different thing.  That question is asking "How can I stop this pausing behaviour, if at all?" whereas this question is asking "how can I get the message echoed after vim has started?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim pauses if echo in .vimrc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171059/vim-pauses-if-echo-in-vimrc-file)

Comment: Additionally to the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9171079/557306), you can also use an auto command as described here: [How to echo custom startup message in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10803527/557306).

Comment: @sidyll - thanks.  I've flagged my question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803527/how-to-echo-custom-startup-message-in-vim

Comment: Thanks for keeping it organised, and happy that you found a solution! Thanks, best wishes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your vimrc:

```
" when Vim starts with no file
if argc() == 0
    autocmd VimEnter * echo "Nr. of Colors: " . &t_Co
end
```